GAMS Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared


      Sets
         i /1*20/
         alias(i,j);
     
     Parameters
         pi(i)   "Profit of item i"
         W       "Width of the container"
         H       "Height of the container"
         D       "Depth of the container"
         wi(i)   "Width of item i"
         hi(i)   "Height of item i"
         di(i)   "Depth of item i";
     
     Variables
         z       "Objective: total profit"
         si(i)   "1 if item i is selected, 0 otherwise"
         xi(i)   "X-coordinate of item i"
         yi(i)   "Y-coordinate of item i"
         zi(i)   "Z-coordinate of item i"
         lij(i,j) "1 if item i is to the left of item j"
         uij(i,j) "1 if item i is below item j"
         bij(i,j) "1 if item i is behind item j";
     
     Binary Variables si, lij, uij, bij;
     
     Positive Variables xi, yi, zi;
     
     Equations
         obj             "Objective function"
         packing1(i,j)   "Non-overlapping constraint for x"
         packing2(i,j)   "Non-overlapping constraint for y"
         packing3(i,j)   "Non-overlapping constraint for z"
         bound_x(i)      "X-bound constraint"
         bound_y(i)      "Y-bound constraint"
         bound_z(i)      "Z-bound constraint";
     
     * Objective: maximize total profit
     obj .. 
         z =e= sum(i, pi(i) * si(i));
     
     * Non-overlapping constraints
     packing1(i,j) $ (i <> j) ..
         xi(i) + wi(i) * si(i) + W * lij(i,j) =l= xi(j) + W * (1 - si(i));
     
     packing2(i,j) $ (i <> j) ..
         yi(i) + hi(i) * si(i) + H * uij(i,j) =l= yi(j) + H * (1 - si(i));
     
     packing3(i,j) $ (i <> j) ..
         zi(i) + di(i) * si(i) + D * bij(i,j) =l= zi(j) + D * (1 - si(i));
     
     * Boundary constraints
     bound_x(i) ..
         xi(i) + wi(i) * si(i) =l= W;
     
     bound_y(i) ..
         yi(i) + hi(i) * si(i) =l= H;
     
     bound_z(i) ..
         zi(i) + di(i) * si(i) =l= D;
     
     Model BinPacking /all/;
     Solve BinPacking using mip maximizing z;

I'm trying to run this code on GAMS. However, it's giving me "Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared" error in packing1(i,j) $ (i <> j) ..  I'm trying to create model for 3D bin packing for rolls. If you know better way, please write it on the comments.

You should do this instead (same for the following errors):
* Non-overlapping constraints
packing1(i,j) $ (ord(i) <> ord(j)) ..
    xi(i) + wi(i) * si(i) + W * lij(i,j) =l= xi(j) + W * (1 - si(i));

Ord returns the relative position of an element in a set.
